# Need some help to reaslize method

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have site with code like:

```
<nav id="main-header-navbar">
  <ul class="navigation-menu-items initialized tablet">
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a href="#1" class="collapsed" title="with submenu">MENU1</a>
    <div id="Level1NavNode1">
      <span class="dropdown-item-title">MENU1</span>
        <ul class="dropdown-items ps-container ps-theme-default">
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
    <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a href="#2" class="collapsed" title="with submenu">MENU2</a>
    <div id="Level1NavNode2">
      <span class="dropdown-item-title">MENU2</span>
        <ul class="dropdown-items ps-container ps-theme-default">
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
          <li>Some link</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I wanna receive in method some string like "MENU1" and count number of "li" tags. I tried something like this:

```
    @FindBy(xpath = "//*[@id=\"main-header-navbar\"]")
    WebElement topMenu;

    public boolean checkSubmenuItemsAndSize(String menuItem, String[] submenus, int size) {
        menuItem = menuItem.toUpperCase();
        int i = 1000;
        try {
            WebElement item = topMenu.findElement(By.id(menuItem));
            for (i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
                item.findElement(By.linkText(submenus[i]));
                logger.info("Item menu" + submenus[i] + "is enabled");
            }
            if (size != item.findElements(By.tagName("li")).size()) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
            return true;
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            logger.error("Incorrect quantity of submenu items");
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("No such submenu item:" + submenus[i]);
            return false;
        }
    }
```

I try to define what menu I need, but it works with reference tag, and I need to move to next div section.
Can I solve this problem without external libraries?

Comment: Maybe you want compare `String[] submenus` with `li` in `MENU1` ? is the value array list available or not with the web ? like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead `id` and `linkText` try use `xpath` bellow:

```
WebElement item = topMenu.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-items ps-container ps-theme-default' and ./preceding-sibling::*[text()='" +menuItem +"']]"));
for (i = 0; i < submenus.length; i++) {
    item.findElement(By.xpath("//ul[@class='dropdown-items ps-container ps-theme-default' and ./preceding-sibling::*[text()='" +menuItem +"']]//li[text()='" +submenus[i] +"']"));
    logger.info("Item menu" + submenus[i] + "is enabled");
}
```